# Remove Duplicate object from Array Deep Check

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, duplicates

I have a array of objects, like:

```
[{
  actionType: 10,
  orderItemId: "3205ae52-ab00-4823-a004-da0cda639065",
  productComponentAction:{
    productComponent:{
      offerId: 10002839,
      parentOfferId: 10003058,
      adoptableProdCompId: undefined
    } 
  }
},
{
  actionType: 10,
  orderItemId: "3205ae52-ab00-4823-2121-da0cda6390ae",
  productComponentAction:{
    productComponent:{
      offerId: 10002839,
      parentOfferId: 10003058,
      adoptableProdCompId: undefined
    } 
  }
}]
```

I want this array to be unique on the basis of `offerId`. If `offerId` is the same, then I want to remove that object from the array.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use a Map, with reduce, and grab the values from the map:

```js
const arr = [{
    actionType: 10,
    orderItemId: "3205ae52-ab00-4823-a004-da0cda639065",
    productComponentAction: {
      productComponent: {
        offerId: 10002839,
        parentOfferId: 10003058,
        adoptableProdCompId: undefined
      }
    }
  },
  {
    actionType: 10,
    orderItemId: "3205ae52-ab00-4823-2121-da0cda6390ae",
    productComponentAction: {
      productComponent: {
        offerId: 10002839,
        parentOfferId: 10003058,
        adoptableProdCompId: undefined
      }
    }
  }
]

const filtered = Array.from(arr.reduce((a, v) => {
  const id = v.productComponentAction.productComponent.offerId
  if(!a.has(id)) a.set(id, v)
  return a
}, new Map()).values())

console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a temporary Map, keyed by whatever you want to be unique. Its constructor accepts [key,value] pairs:

```js
let data = [{actionType: 10, orderItemId: "3205ae52-ab00-4823-a004-da0cda639065", productComponentAction:{productComponent:{ offerId: 10002839, parentOfferId: 10003058,     adoptableProdCompId: undefined } }},{actionType: 10,orderItemId: "3205ae52-ab00-4823-2121-da0cda6390ae", productComponentAction:{ productComponent:{ offerId: 10002839,      parentOfferId: 10003058, adoptableProdCompId: undefined  }  }}];

let uniques = Array.from(new Map(
     data.map(item => [item.productComponentAction.productComponent.offerId, item])
).values());
    
console.log(uniques);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object which would have `objectId` as its key, like this:

```
var target = {};
for (let item of myArray) {
    if (target[item.objectId] === undefined) {
        target[item.objectId] = item;
    }
}
```

and then, when you attempt to add to this array, you just check whether the item with the certain key already exists.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use `reduce` method. It checks whether there is a property with the same key and if it exists it creates a key, otherwise it does nothing:

```
arr.reduce((a, c)=> {
    a[c.productComponentAction.productComponent.offerId] = 
        a[c.productComponentAction.productComponent.offerId] || {...c};
    return a;
}, {})
```

An example:

```js
let arr = [{
  actionType: 10,
  orderItemId: "3205ae52-ab00-4823-a004-da0cda639065",
  productComponentAction:{
    productComponent:{
      offerId: 10002839,
      parentOfferId: 10003058,
      adoptableProdCompId: undefined
    }
  }
},
{
  actionType: 10,
  orderItemId: "3205ae52-ab00-4823-2121-da0cda6390ae",
  productComponentAction:{
    productComponent:{
      offerId: 10002839,
      parentOfferId: 10003058,
      adoptableProdCompId: undefined
    }
  }
}];

let filteredList = arr.reduce((a, c)=> {
  a[c.productComponentAction.productComponent.offerId] = 
      a[c.productComponentAction.productComponent.offerId] || {...c};
  return a;
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(filteredList));
```